# Segmentation fault trying to read until header is encountered in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am new to C so pardon the simplicity of the question. I am trying to write a function (as a lib, so it must be robust) that constantly reads one byte (EDIT: from a serial port) until a header start byte is encountered. If it finds it, it will read in the rest of the header and payload and store it in a struct. The start of my code looks something like this (some pseudocode will be included):

```
soh_read = 0;
bytes_read = 0;
bytes_left = 1;

do{
    n = read(fd, buf + bytes_read, bytes_left);
    if(n < 0){
        if(errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK && errno != EINTR){
            return -1;
        }
    }else{
        bytes_read += n;
        if(!soh_read){
            if(buf[0] != SOH){
                bytes_read = 0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        soh_read = 1;
        //read header ...
        //read payload ...

}while(timeout is not reached);
```

I assumed I could reset the bytes_read to 0 if SOH is not encountered and try to read in the buf[0] position again, overwriting the garbage it previously read. But it seems like this a case of a buffer overflow and why I am getting a segmentation fault? Why would that not work though? If so, what is the best way to go about this? I wanted to start at buf[0] so it'd be easy to keep track of each of the message fields. Just trying to learn from the experts here, thanks.

Comment: could you post a link with the whole code, put it in pastebin or something

Comment: bytes_read += n; might be the problem, it might overflow the buffer before ir finds the header. If you don't use the data anyway what's the user incrementing? increment only when you read the useful data

Comment: titus, I don't think all the code is needed (if SOH byte is not read, it never hits the rest of my code). The problem here is resetting bytes_read to 0 and reading again into that position of the buffer. I know it's the cause because it segfaults on the second read of 1 byte. The rest of my code should be okay, this is the only place I explicitly reset the bytes_read count (and the reason was because I wanted to ensure SOH was in buf[0]).

Comment: bytes_read is also used to read the header and payload, and those are all calculated correctly. I guess my real question is how would I keep reading one byte into buf[0] until SOH is hit?

Comment: you usually get segfault when you access memory past the allocated bounds, don't see how resetting to 0 might be the problem

Comment: as it is put an astronomical value for the buf size array

Comment: Added more code to OP, please let me know if you see something really strange.

Comment: @Jack let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1073/discussion-between-titus-and-jack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've left out some information crucial to diagnosing the problem with your code as it stands. The single most important thing is (probably) whether your SOH might occur later in the file than you've allowed room for in your `buf`.

That said, however, I think I'd do things rather differently: since you apparently don't need (or even care about) the data that precedes the SOH anyway, why not just read all that data into one character, overwriting the previous value at each iteration, and only save more than one byte of data after you encounter the SOH so you actually have a use for it.

```
do { 
    read(fd, buf, 1);
    if (n<0 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK && /* ... */)
       return -1;
} while (buf[0] != SOH and !timeout_reached);

// read the header here
```

Comment: I guess that was what I was trying to emulate. I didn't explicitly do it this way because I wanted to keep it clean with one read statement (although obviously it will be called multiple times). I added more code to the OP so you could see what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Jack: if you want to use only one read, the obvious alternative would be to increment `bytes_read` only when `soh_read` is true. Personally, I think I'd prefer separate calls to `read` though. You might consider breaking it into two functions to get something like `skip_to_header(fd); read_header(fd);`.